# Pushwoosh Application ID string value

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hullo,
I am trying to use the pushwoosh push service but got stuck when setting the info.plist as they suggested. They mention setting a ID with key Pushwoosh_APPID which is fine and good but with value: "your Pushwoosh Application ID string value". I tried using with little conviction the Application Code but when I compile I receive this log that seems to confirm my doubts:

```
2012-10-27 15:58:45.722 Taxi Profi[6130:907] Initializing application: (null), (null)
2012-10-27 15:58:46.309 Taxi Profi[6130:4b07] Sending request: {"request":{"hwid":"7f4e5685d3a4978b8ecb49fa30d4fc8b", "application":"B186B-B66EA", "badge":0}}
2012-10-27 15:58:46.311 Taxi Profi[6130:4b07] To urL https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/setBadge
2012-10-27 15:58:46.359 Taxi Profi[6130:5207] Sending request: {"request":{"hwid":"7f4e5685d3a4978b8ecb49fa30d4fc8b", "application":"B186B-B66EA", "badge":0}}
2012-10-27 15:58:46.361 Taxi Profi[6130:5207] To urL https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/setBadge
2012-10-27 15:58:46.993 Taxi Profi[6130:907] Error registering for push notifications. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x1e5c0790 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
2012-10-27 15:58:47.339 Taxi Profi[6130:4b07] Response "200 no error": string: {"status_code":210,"status_message":"Device not found","response":null}
2012-10-27 15:58:47.341 Taxi Profi[6130:4b07] setBadges completed
2012-10-27 15:58:47.399 Taxi Profi[6130:5207] Response "200 no error": string: {"status_code":210,"status_message":"Device not found","response":null}
2012-10-27 15:58:47.404 Taxi Profi[6130:5207] setBadges completed
```

Their example list this long code:4F0C807E51EC77.93591449 I do not know where they take from.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Pushwoosh now uses another format for App ID, such as "FE748-9A37E". You can find it in Control Panel.

Comment: Yes, that is what I used, yet the app gave the error log above when executed, with a code 3000 that I did not find in the documentation.

Comment: @user1323536 i reffered one tutorial , but there i required pushwhoosh app id. so as you said we can get it from control panel, so can help me with this.?

Comment: The Pushwoosh App Id is the Application Code that is shown on the left side corner of your application page in Pushwoosh control panel, it looks like XXXXX-XXXXX

Answer (score 0):

The Pushwoosh staff explained me there was a problem in the APple web site that hampered using their manual procedure. They were kind enough to enable me to use the Automatic one and it all worked finely albeit with two codes: on e for development and one for release. What doubles the testing procedure.